# Java - Read Text File, Store Contents in ArrayList, Print ArrayList

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

I have to write a program that:

1. prompts the user for the name of the input file,
2. reads the data from the input file and store information about the cars in an array list of Car objects,
3. prints the unsorted data from the array list to the screen, as shown below:

```
Enter the name of the input file -> carlot.txt

The Unsorted Array List of Cars

[Honda, Prelude, 1998] 
[Honda, Accord, 1998]
[Honda, Ridgeline, 2006]
[Ford, Taurus, 1996]
[Mitsubishi, Eclipse, 1996]
[Mitsubishi, Galant, 2015]
[Ford, Fusion, 2010]
[Mazda, Protege 5, 2003]
[Mazda, Protege 5, 2002]
[Isuzu, Trooper, 2002]
```

I cannot figure out how to do these first three steps.

My code:

```
package carsorter;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CarSorter 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            String userFileName;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the input file - > ");
            userFileName = in.next();
            System.out.println();

            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(userFileName));
            ArrayList<Car> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
            while (file.hasNext()) 
            {
                list1.add(new Car(file.nextInt(), file.next(), file.next()));
            }
            Car[] list2 = list1.toArray(new Car[list1.size()]);
            System.out.println("The Unsorted Array List of Cars");
            int i;
            for (i=0; i < list1.size(); i++) 
            {
                System.out.println(list1.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

It gives me the file not found exception when I compile the program even though I just created the file and saved it to my computer.

I also have two classes that go with this project and will add them if necessary/wanted. So basically just need help figuring out how to read a text file from the user, add the contents of the text file to an ArrayList, and print out the contents of the ArrayList in a formatted way (I have a toString() method in one of my classes).

Comment: You should indicate the path to the file and not just the name

Comment: You mean in the `Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(userFileName));` or when I run the program and type in the file name? (the latter didn't work) @realUser404

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you only enter the **name** of the file you want to read (Ej. foo.txt). If that is the case then you shouldn't pass it as is to the `new File()` constructor since that constructor expects an absolute path (or a path relative to the JVM being executed) so you should enter the **full absolute file path** following the file name in your prompt (Ej. /home/user/foo.txt or c:\documents\foo.txt).

If that is not the case, you at first should print the path entered in the prompt into the variable `userFileName` to see if the path is correct.

I would recommend you after you create your `File` instance with the path, you check if it exists and if it can be read by its `exists()` and `canRead()` instance methods.

Comment: Yeah, the sample output in the project directions only show carlot.txt, not the full file path. I'm really new to OOP (and programming in general), so forgive me, but are you saying to get rid of the `Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(userFileName));` and then type in the file path when I run the program?

Comment: No, I don't mean that you get rid of that line. I mean that the user should enter the full path along with the file name or you should concatenate the path after the user enters the file name so you can successfully read the file.